# Converting a struct to char array using memcpy

Tags: c++, c, arrays, struct

I am trying to convert the following struct to a char array so that I can send it via the serial port.

```
struct foo
{
    uint16_t voltage;
    char ID ;
    char TempByte;
    char RTCday[2];
    char RTCmonth[2];
    char RTCyear[2];
    char RTChour[2];
    char RTCmin[2];
    char Sepbyte;   
}dvar = { 500, 'X' , '>' , "18" , "10" , "15" , "20" , "15" , '#'};
```

I then convert it to a char array using the following:

```
char b[sizeof(struct foo)];
memcpy(b, &dvar, sizeof(struct foo));
```

However for some reason I get these trailing values in the char array

```
0x0A 0xFF
```

I initially thought it was getting the values because when i cast it to a char array it was effectively casting it to a string so I though the was the NULL '\0'

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I don't see where is structure `datadownload` and what is the size of it

Comment: What do you mean by "trailing values"? How do you examine the contents of the array? And are you programming C or C++? The semantics could be different. On an unrelated note, have you though of using a union instead?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member

Comment: If you convert this to a `char` array, nobody is going to add a NULL terminator for you. You need to do that yourself.

Comment: datadownload is the foo structure. I was renaming it but forgot to rename it in memcpy. I renamed it in the post. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: I'm evaluating it by sending it to serial port. I just pass that the char array and increments until it reaches the end of the array

Comment: @Lundin I almost thought that padding was the issue but my struct has no padding or white spaces in it.

Comment: Your `memcpy` is useless in the example, the cast happens with passing `&dvar` as the parameter of type `void *`. This would also work: `char *b = &dvar;` or better `char *b = (char *)&dvar;`

Comment: @Lundin I also set the exact size of the struct myself without using sizeof and I still get the same issue

Comment: @CSharper The bug is either related to struct padding or to missing null termination. At any rate, it is non-portable because of struct padding.

Comment: Please just don't do this. If you need data in a particular byte format to send over a serial or network link, write proper code to serialize it into that format. Don't use things like `memcpy` on integers or `sizeof` on structures that depend on details of the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a sneaky suspicion you are using an 8bit microcontroller!
You can debug by printing `b[sizeof(foo)]`, and `b[sizeof(foo)+1]`
These will be your two characters.
If you noticed, you should not be referencing these, they are outside the bounds of your char array. eg n element array [0..(n-1)] (copied from your struct)

If you add an unused element to your struct(or increase the size of your final member) the char array can be terminated '\0' -compiler probably wants to do this.

Or do a pointer assignment as @Melebius has shown.

Answer (score 4):

On modern processors, sizeof(struct data download) needs to be aligned on 32bits boundaries. Your data structure size is 8 chars + 1 short (16 bits) integer. The compiler needs to add 2 chars to the size of the structure to be able to handle it correctly when assigning it. 
Since you're doing communication over a serial line and know exactly what you're sending, you might as well specify the exact number of bytes you're willing to send over your serial lines: 2 +/*1 short */ + 8 (8 bytes).